# Ending with "..." when Flutter Text exceeds a certain length

Tags: android, flutter

I have an application like this:

[image]

As you can see, there is a talma here. The reason for this overflow is that the `Text` is long and does not fit in the `Container`.

I want the `Text` to end with "..." if its content exceeds 14 characters. So only 11 characters will appear in Text.

How can I do that?

Codes:

```
  SizedBox(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
    child: ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: [
        for (var i = 0; i < Products.length; i++)
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
          child: GestureDetector(
            child: Card(
              elevation: 0,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              ),
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.37,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xFF3F3F46),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                      child: Image.network(Products[i].data()["Image"], fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 110, height: 110),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.015),
                    // ********** NAME:
                    Text(Products[i].data()["Name"], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontFamily: "Inter Regular", color: Color(0xFFD4D4D8)), textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is not mandatory to have exactly 11 characters, but instead let the UI fit as best as you can, by adding the following property to the `Text` widget:

```
overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis
```

If you want it to be excactly 11 characters + three '`.`' if it is longer than 14 characters, then you can instead do the following:

```
text.length > 14 ? '${text.substring(0, 11)}...' : text
```

where `text` in your case is `Products[i].data()["Name"]`

Answer (score 1):

```
Flexible(
child: new Container(
padding: new EdgeInsets.only(right: 13.0),
child: new Text(
  'Text largeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee',
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  style: new TextStyle(
    fontSize: 13.0,
    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
    color: new Color(0xFF212121),
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
  ),
),
```

),
),

use **overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,**

Answer (score 1):

Use `overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,`

```
Text(
 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  style: new TextStyle(
    fontSize: 16
  ),
),
```